# How can I solve xampp server not connecting to the browser

Tags: wordpress, xampp

How can I solve xampp server not connecting to the browser

I tried connecting the xampp local server to the browser but it's not working

Comment: Please check error log of Xampp server

Answer (score 0):

check on your applications administrator and see all the programs running and if any is using same port you need to stop it. if you are in a mac is in the activity monitor click on memory and check all ports in use.